# Integración de PayPal mediante la API de Google Pay en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api, paypal

Como podrán observar en el titulo de la pregunta, necesito integrar el medio de pago via PayPal pero usando GooglePay en `Android Studio`. Por los momentos mi plataforma de pagos solo acepta Tarjetas de Credito y Debito.

Cabe destacar que en la documentación de Google Pay indican como debe quedar el archivo `JSON` para la petición del pago, pero no explican como se crea el mismo mediante `Java`.

Comment: Bienvenido, considera revisar [ask] y realiza modificaciones a tu pregunta. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico.

Comment: Haz pensado utilizar ¿ [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) ? es un servicio de PayPal,el SDK de PayPal como tal está obsoleto. Además, te recomiendo no implementar demasiados sistemas de pago, porque tus ganancias se pueden ver afectadas. Google cobra un 30% de las ventas. Emplear otro sistema en conjunto con Google Pay no te generará muchos beneficios a menos que vendas productos costosos. Ahora bien, si lo entiendes necesario, para manejar los productos desde su catálogo y evitar desarrollar tus propios productos, adelante.

Comment: La cuestión es que no cuento con un servidor para procesar pagos, por eso no puedo usar braintree. Se requiere usar unicamente Google Pay, según la cartera de productos que se maneja si se verán ganancias. Es muy importante recordar que no busco implementar la API de PayPal porque se que esta obsoleta, lo que se busca es la configuración de google pay para aceptar pagos paypal

Comment: Por el momento, según lo que he investigado, no es posible hacer una integración nativa o no hay documentación para eso. En los [FAQS de Google](https://bit.ly/2gZHhkO) te dice claramente en el apartado que ni siquiera es posible hacerlo a través de `Google Play`, sino por Web Browser, dejando claro que esto es solo una integración web al igual que [documentación para linkear PayPal](https://bit.ly/2YhxD7D). Si con el request te genera un Popup web, a lo mejor deberías cargar un WebView e inyectarle un JS a través de una Interfaz de Android, pero no es muy seguro.